# Dynamically Changing the layout of an Activity

Tags: android, viewflipper, android-framelayout

I am working on Tabular data.  My screen has 3 tabs. All three tabs are part of one single activity. And each tab is inflated with separate layouts.

My requirement is that one of the tab's layout can change dynamically. Now since it is a part of an activity , I can not create another activity. Creating another activiy will affect other tabs.

SO basically , I want to know how can we change the layout of a screen dynamicaaly. Should i use ViewFlipper or Framelayout?

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using the fragments , try for that following links may help you..

[Android Fragment Basics](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html)

[Android Fragment Example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use viewpager, actionbar(sherlock actionbar for lower version) and fragments for this.
Here are some examples for you

1. [official Document for ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)
2. [androidsolution4u](http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/2012/10/android-dialogs-tutorial-for-begginer.html)
3. [android-er.blogspot](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/06/viewpager.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible:

Write your xml file like this:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#262626"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  //design for 1st tab

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  //design for 2nd tab

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  //design for 3rd tab

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#acacac"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/1stTab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/2ndTab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/1stTab"
                 />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/3rdTab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/2ndTab"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now in your .java file do something like this:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View layout1 = (View) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
    View layout2 = (View) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
    View layout3 = (View) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout3);
    Button menu1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.1stTab);
    Button menu2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.2ndTab);
    Button menu3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.3rdTab);
    layout3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    layout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    menu1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {

            layout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layout3.setVisibility(View.GONE);               
            layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     //do your rest tabbing work of 1stTab
        }
    });
     menu2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {

            layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layout3.setVisibility(View.GONE);               
            layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     //do your rest tabbing work of 2ndTab
        }
    });
     menu3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {

            layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);               
            layout3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       //do your rest tabbing work of 3rdTab
        }
    });
 }
```

This will might help you.